# NetworkImage cannot be assigned to type Widget

Tags: flutter

I tried to create add an image to my ListView by doing the following

```
new ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new NetworkImage('my_image_url')
  ]
)
```

and got the following error:

> The element type 'NetworkImage' can't be assigned to the list type
>   'Widget'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[NetworkImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/NetworkImage-class.html) isn't a Widget, instead it:

> Fetches the given URL from the network, associating it with the given
>   scale.

Thus, it's used in Widgets like CircleAvatar to provide the source for its image.

The correct way to add an image via a url is to use Image.network('url'):

```
new ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.network('my_image_url')
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`NetworkImage` doesn't just:

> Fetches the given URL from the network, associating it with the given scale.

It can be used to display an image. In fact you will need it for something called `DecoratedBox`, which IS a Widget.

Compared to the simple `Image.network('my_url')`, using `DecoratedBox` has a few advantages. Because you can *alter* that image.
You have access to filters, slice, shadows, or even borders.